# How to I add an item to a list with class in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have to convert my c# into vb but it didn't convert 100%, I'm stuck on adding items to lists with class objects.

I get error here (Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to '_Default.Courses') on the course list add:

```
Public Class Courses
    Public courseName As String
    Public qualName As String
    Public providerName As String
End Class
```

...

```
While r.Read
    Dim coursename As String = r("courseName").ToString
    Dim qualname As String = r("qualName").ToString
    Dim providername As String = r("providerName").ToString
    courseList.Add(New Courses() With {
        Key.courseName = coursename,
        Key.qualName = qualname,
        Key.providerName = providername
    })
End While
```

...

And this is the original c# code:

```
while (r.Read())
{
    string coursename = r["courseName"].ToString();
    string qualname = r["qualName"].ToString();
    string providername = r["providerName"].ToString();

    courseList.Add(new Courses
    {
        courseName = coursename,
        qualName = qualname,
        providerName = providername
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as :

```
While r.Read
    Dim coursename As String = r("courseName").ToString
    Dim qualname As String = r("qualName").ToString
    Dim providername As String = r("providerName").ToString
    courseList.Add(New Courses() With {
        .courseName = coursename,
        .qualName = qualname,
        .providerName = providername
    })
End While
```